# Why use a Lagrangian at all to derive the laws of motions, and not just the action?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action

Assume I have an action defined as

$$
S[g]=R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|}
$$

By variational principle, I get

$$
\delta S[g]=\frac{\delta (R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|})}{\delta g}\delta g
$$

which gives the Einstein field equations.

---

If I use the Lagrangian:

$$
S[g]=\int R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|} dxdydzdt
$$

By variational principle, I get

$$
\delta S[g]=\int \frac{\delta ( R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|})}{\delta g} \delta g dxdydzdt
$$

In all derivation I have seen, the author claims that the variational principle must hold for all variations of $\delta g$ and this implies that the integral is revoked, and one gets:

$$
\delta S[g]=\frac{\delta (R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|})}{\delta g}\delta g
$$

which is the same as above.

---

So, as far as the equations of motions are concerned,

$$
S[g]=R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|} \tag{1}
$$

is the same as

$$
S[g]=\int R[t,x,y,z]\sqrt{-|g|} dxdydzdt \tag{2}
$$

... ? What does (2) gives us that (1) doesn't?

Comment: Your first equation is not an action.

Comment: In particular, the functional derivative is not the same as the partial derivative. In the second formulation, you are free to use integration by parts to get rid of derivatives on $\delta g$, so you can actually write the variation as (something) times $\delta g$. It’s not clear how you do this outside an integral.

Comment: @JahanClaes What specifically does not make my first equation an action. The definition I have is $S$ takes as input a function $\mathcal{C}$ and outputs a scalar. My first equation outputs a function and not a scalar. Is this the problem?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: The output is a scalar density at a spacetime point, not a scalar number.

Comment: This post (v1) seems to use non-standard terminology.

Comment: One thing I have found helpful is to note that the Lagrangian came before Hamilton's Principle.  Once you have Hamilton's Principle (which I think is getting hand-waved into the equations in your derivations), the connection between Lagrangians and actions gets much closer.  I haven't done the math (which is why this is a comment rather than an answer), but that might be the effect that's leading you down this path.

Answer (score 1):

The variational derivative is applied to [**functionals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)), as opposed to functions. Functionals take functions and return real numbers. You set the variation to zero to find which **function** would give you the correct equations of motion.

Your first expression is not a functional. It takes the space-time coordinates and it returns a number. You can think of it as a functional if you were to fix the space-time coordinates but then setting the variation to zero, would return a function, which gives an extremum at a single point, like an ordinary derivative would. But that is **definitely not** the equations of motion. The equations of motion are arrived at when you find a function that minimizes the integral of $R[t,x,y,z] \sqrt{-|g|}$.

So in short, (2) allows you to minimize the integral of the function over the whole of space-time, whereas (1) would do it only at a point.

As a final point, I would like to say that a lot of the time with these problems, in order to arrive at the correct equations of motion, you use properties of the integral such as integration by parts and integrals over boundaries to perform the correct minimization.

I hope this helps.

EDIT:
You have swapped the definitions of the action and the Lagrangian everywhere in your question.  Perhaps that's what's leading to your confusion. The action is defined to be the integral of the Lagrangian over space-time, whereas in your question the Lagrangian is the integral of the action, at least in the way you have phrased things.